# 歓迎しましょう vs 歓迎します vs ようこそ

Tags: meaning, word-choice, usage, etymology, word-usage

What is the difference between:

1. 歓迎しましょう (Kangei shimashou)
2. 歓迎します (Kangei shimasu)
3. ようこそ (Yōkoso)

They all mean "welcome" but in which occasions should we use which more appropriately. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you see the first?

Comment: You can check using google translate. You can get the first.

Comment: No, I can't and I give credit to Google Translate at least for that.

Answer (score 2):

1. 歓迎しましょう is literally *Let's welcome*. If you are with a friend A, and read an email that another friend B is coming to Japan next week, then you say to A "(Bを)歓迎しましょう".
2. 歓迎します is *I (will) welcome*.  This is usually used with explicit objects and sounds somewhat formal (so common in writing). You can write to a guest あなたを歓迎します.  The objects does not have to be animate: 質問を歓迎します *I welcome questions*.
3. ようこそ is the only option if you want a phrase to put in a banner (I mean a large sheet of cloth you hold e.g. at the gate of airport). It is also the most appropriate phrase to say to a guest who just arrived.

Comment: many thanks for the answer - I voted up. I am not sure who voted down my question - but it will be great to give an answer how shall I improve

Comment: @wonderich I didn't vote on the question, but some users may feel that the question does not show evidence of prior research. In the comments you indicated that you used Google translate, but google translate is notoriously unreliable and not considered sufficient prior research by many.

Answer (score 2):

ようこそ is not a verb but a greeting meaning "Welcome!" As a word said to a **visitor**, ようこそ is by far the most common among the three. "Welcome to Las Vegas" is almost always ラスベガスへようこそ or ラスベガスにようこそ. 歓迎します is correct if you want to speak snobbishly like an aristocrat, but it sounds unnatural in most cases.

歓迎します is a verb, and is used mainly outside a context of welcoming a visitor. For example, "We welcome constructive comments" is 建設的な意見を歓迎します. You cannot use ようこそ in a case like this.

歓迎しましょう is the [volitional form](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-volitional-form-you/) of 歓迎します. Roughly speaking, this ～しょう adds the nuance of "Let us" or "Let me" in English. This form is typically used when you've just made up your mind to welcome someone, or when you somehow need to emphasize your decision to welcome someone, or when you want to convince others to welcome someone else.